# Blank descriptions in kext enable dialog

Tags: kernel-extensions

Attempting to enable kexts in the System Preferences UI. I noticed that there are two checkboxes with blank descriptions next to them. Where are these values stored? Is there a command line interface to inspect the values?

[image: kext settings]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Could you try `systemextensionsctl list`?

Comment: That did show them. Sophos extensions. Thanks!

Comment: I‘m glad it worked! I‘ve posted an answer and would appreciate it if you marked it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a command line interface to inspect the values?

Yes, use this command:

```
systemextensionsctl list
```

to list all installed system extensions.